# Series Proof Question

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification, convergence-divergence

By considering the partial sums for S, that is
Sn =1+2+3+···n
show that the infinite series S does not converge.

However in this video http://www.numberphile.com/videos/analytical_continuation1.html
it states that this series converges to -1/12? How can this be?

Comment: That's what you call an "abuse of notation".

Comment: It doesn't _converge_ to $-\dfrac1{12}$. It sums to $-\dfrac1{12}$… if you're willing to butcher the meaning of "sum". The _normal_ meaning of "sum" (of an infinite series) is the limit of the partial sums, but that's clearly not what they're using there. When you try and assign a value to divergent sums, you're not actually _summing_ them in any normal sense. (Even if the result is meaningful somehow, it's still a bit of an abuse of terminology to call it it's "sum".)

Comment: So is this video incorrect? @columbus8myhw

Comment: @oander66 More or less. Mind you, it does add to $-\dfrac1{12}$ in a sense, but in a very convoluted sense that really isn't what you'd expect when they say that it's "what you get when you add them all together". (Besides: Call $S=1+2+3+4+5+\dotsb$. Let $S'=0+1+2+3+4+\dotsb$, and let $S''=0+0+1+2+3+\dotsb$. If they all had sums, we would clearly have $S=S'=S''$. Thus, we would have $0=S-2S'+S''$. But, if you actually add them up term-by-term, you'd find that $S-2S'+S''=1$. Contradiction.)

Comment: Did you search the site at all? To put it mildly, this is not the first tiime this question has been asked here :-)